# Convert Nested Array into Columns in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten

I have a table column with nested arrays in a Snowflake database. I want to convert the nested array into columns in the manner shown below in Snowflake SQL.

Table Name: SENSOR_DATA

The RX column is of data type VARIANT. The nested arrays will not always be 3 as shown below. There are cases where there are 20,000 nested arrays, and other cases where there are none.

```
| ID |             RX              |
|----|-----------------------------|
| 1  |[[0, 15], [1, 50], [2, 34.2]]|
| 2  |[[0, 20], [1, 25]]           |
| 3  |[[0, 100], [1, 42], [2, 76]] |
```

I want to achieve something like this from the table above:

```
| ID |Col0 | Col1| Col2|
|----|-----|-----|-----|
| 1  |  15 |  50 | 34.2|
| 2  |  20 |  25 | NULL|
| 3  | 100 |  42 | 76  |
```

Comment: What will you do with 60,000(!) columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets recreate that table:

```
create table sensor_data as 
  select column1 id, parse_json(column2) rx
  from values (1, '[[0, 15], [1, 50], [2, 34.2]]')
             ,(2, '[[0, 20], [1, 25]]')
             ,(3, '[[0, 100], [1, 42], [2, 76]]');
```

Then get the distinct column keys that you have:

```
select distinct r.value[0] from sensor_data, table(flatten(input=>rx)) r;
```

| R.VALUE[0] |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |

Given we want this to be dynamic, the next step is just to check with static SQL it gives us the correct answer:

```
 select id
    ,max(iff(r.value[0] = 0, r.value[1], null)) as col_0
    ,max(iff(r.value[0] = 1, r.value[1], null)) as col_1
    ,max(iff(r.value[0] = 2, r.value[1], null)) as col_2
 from sensor_data, table(flatten(input=>rx)) r
 group by 1
 order by 1;
```

| ID | COL_0 | COL_1 | COL_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 | 50 | 34.2 |
| 2 | 20 | 25 | null |
| 3 | 100 | 42 | 76 |

write now to do this dynamically:

```
declare
  sql string;
  c1 cursor for select distinct r.value[0] as key from sensor_data, table(flatten(input=>rx)) r;
begin
  sql := 'select id ';
  for record in c1 do
    sql := sql || ',max(iff(r.value[0] = '|| record.key::text ||', r.value[1], null)) as col_' || record.key::text;
  end for;
  sql := sql || ' from sensor_data, table(flatten(input=>rx)) r  group by 1  order by 1';
  return sql;
end;
```

which gives us:

> select id ,max(iff(r.value[0] = 0, r.value[1](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/loops.html), null)) as col_0,max(iff(r.value[0] = 1, r.value[1](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/loops.html), null)) as col_1,max(iff(r.value[0] = 2, r.value[1](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/loops.html), null)) as col_2 from sensor_data, table(flatten(input=>rx)) r  group by 1  order by 1

which when run gives us the expected results.

so now we want to run that:

```
declare
  sql string;
  res resultset;
  c1 cursor for select distinct r.value[0] as key from sensor_data, table(flatten(input=>rx)) r;
begin
  sql := 'select id ';
  for record in c1 do
    sql := sql || ',max(iff(r.value[0] = '|| record.key::text ||', r.value[1], null)) as col_' || record.key::text;
  end for;
  sql := sql || ' from sensor_data, table(flatten(input=>rx)) r  group by 1  order by 1';
  
  res := (execute immediate :sql);
  return table (res);
end;
```

gives:

| ID | COL_0 | COL_1 | COL_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 | 50 | 34.2 |
| 2 | 20 | 25 | null |
| 3 | 100 | 42 | 76 |

based of code from these sections of the manual:

[Working with loops](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/loops.html)

[Working with Resultsets](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/resultsets.html)

### With extra "tricky data" and the mentioned ORDER BY:

```
create or replace table sensor_data as 
  select column1 id, parse_json(column2) rx
  from values (1, '[[0, 15], [1, 50], [2, 34.2]]')
             ,(2, '[[0, 20], [1, 25]]')
             ,(3, '[[0, 100], [1, 42], [2, 76]]')
             ,(4, '[[0,20],[30,50], [45, 100]]');
```

```
declare
  sql string;
  res resultset;
  c1 cursor for select distinct r.value[0] as key from sensor_data, table(flatten(input=>rx)) r order by key;
begin
  sql := 'select id ';
  for record in c1 do
    sql := sql || ',max(iff(r.value[0] = '|| record.key::text ||', r.value[1], null)) as col_' || record.key::text;
  end for;
  sql := sql || ' from sensor_data, table(flatten(input=>rx)) r  group by 1  order by 1';
  
  res := (execute immediate :sql);
  return table (res);
end;
```

gives:

| ID | COL_0 | COL_1 | COL_2 | COL_30 | COL_45 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 | 50 | 34.2 | null | null |
| 2 | 20 | 25 | null | null | null |
| 3 | 100 | 42 | 76 | null | null |
| 4 | 20 | null | null | 50 | 100 |

### So yes, but that's the MAX doing:

so if we go back in to original data

```
create or replace table sensor_data as 
  select column1 id, parse_json(column2) rx
  from values (1, '[[0, 15], [1, 50], [2, 34.2]]')
             ,(2, '[[0, 20], [1, 25]]')
             ,(3, '[[0, 100], [1, 42], [2, 76]]');
```

and alter the code to not have the MAX and the GROUP BY

```
 select id
    ,iff(r.value[0] = 0, r.value[1], null) as col_0
    ,iff(r.value[0] = 1, r.value[1], null) as col_1
    ,iff(r.value[0] = 2, r.value[1], null) as col_2
 from sensor_data, table(flatten(input=>rx)) r
 order by 1;
```

we see:

| ID | COL_0 | COL_1 | COL_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 | null | null |
| 1 | null | 50 | null |
| 1 | null | null | 34.2 |
| 2 | 20 | null | null |
| 2 | null | 25 | null |
| 3 | 100 | null | null |
| 3 | null | 42 | null |
| 3 | null | null | 76 |

so we can see those values getting unrolled, now the GROUP BY id, is going to roll those three id's up, thus for col0 we have `15, null, null` MAX takes the higest value, and 15 is higher that null so that is what is keep. This is the process this is working on.

Comment: The cursor query should have a order by if you need those columns to be in order.

Comment: What if the indices were not always in that order. What if it was [[0,20],[30,50], [45, 100]]? How can I have it where it is col_0, col_30, col_45? This will not always be the same.

Comment: The above code solve this exact case. did you try to "tricky" data?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much! Would you be able to give a brief explanation of the 'With extra "tricky data" and the mentioned ORDER BY' part?

Comment: The answer in the extra section was just the answer from the prior section. I only  changed it by an ORDER BY to the cursor query, like I mentioned in my comment. So the output columns are presented in the nicer order. The whole point of that section was to show you that this code works, for any random combination of input, which is what you original asked for. I am not sure which part to do not get, thus what you would like to have an explanation for?

Comment: Yeah, I tried it and it worked perfectly! Ahh, I am a little confused on the iff part, and how your code is being able to get the null for the vectors that don't have the same number of nested lists.

Comment: `IFF( logic, value_1, value_2)` is the same as `CASE logic THEN value_1 ELSE value_2 END` but smaller, often when people use the CASE form if the ELSE is null they skip that, so you have to implicitly know what the case is doing. But otherwise they are 100% the same thing. columns have null for values that have no content, but the `value_2` is null, so MAX over many null's is null.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. How is the MAX helping in our logic?

Comment: we use that to handle "all those nulls, and keep the only non-null value" because non-null values are larger than null.

Comment: Why do we use a cursor in this example?

Comment: @Rookie-XB are surprised as you have something simpler in mind? or do you not see the purpose it is providing? Anyways here's the doc's for it: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/loops.html#cursor-based-for-loops

Answer (score 1):

Using [] to access array elements:

```
SELECT ID, RX[0][1] AS col1,  RX[1][1] AS col1, RX[2][1] AS col2
FROM SENSOR_DATA;
```

Comment: My nested array size is not fixed. I could have 60,000 nested arrays, so writing it out the way you suggested is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for but this is close

```
with sensor_data as (
  select column1 id, parse_json(column2) rx
  from values (1, '[[0, 15], [1, 50], [2, 34.2]]')
             ,(2, '[[0, 20], [1, 25]]')
             ,(3, '[[0, 100], [1, 42], [2, 76]]')
       as vals
),
flat as (
select id, val.value[1] arrvalue
  from sensor_data,
  lateral flatten(input => sensor_data.rx, outer => true) val
 )
select
     id
    ,listagg(arrvalue, ',') rx_list
from flat
group by id
order by id
  ;
```

```
ID  RX_LIST
1   15,50,34.2
2   20,25
3   100,42,76
```

Comment: that's not quite what I need

Comment: Understood, but not really feasible to dynamically generate upwards of 20,000 columns. Either a list or an array would be more manageable. If you truly must have thousands of columns, you will need a procedural approach to dynamically generate the result set.